# how does one reset the value of a text input in html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, I have a code which resets the value of a text input using JavaScript which activates after pressing the space button :

```
document.getElementById("input").value=""
```

but the input text input always has a white-space in front of it which I can only remove by pressing backspace on the actual input.

Is there any way to remove the white-space at the front automatically using native JavaScript

Since everybody asking the other code, here it is

```
function checkWholeWord(){
    var value1=document.getElementById("input").value
    console.log(value1)
    var array2=document.getElementById("typed").innerHTML.split(" ")
    if(value1==array2[x]){
      console.log('it worked')
      document.getElementById("input").value=""
      incrementX()
    }
}

function handleKeyPress(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        return false
    } else if(e.keyCode==32){
        checkWholeWord();
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is not `document.getElementById ("input"). value = ""`, but the problem is something else. give more html and css code

Comment: please add the code snipet that activates the input

Comment: @Bop , If you using this "document.getElementById("input").value="" " means value="" then it should not generate whitespace,Please check your code.

Comment: @Bop Can you make us a demo?